# How do you read multiple .txt files into R?

Tags: r, lapply, fread, read.table, readr

I'm using R to visualize some data all of which is in .txt format. There are a few hundred files in a directory and I want to load it all into one table, in one shot.

Any help?

EDIT:

Listing the files is not a problem. But I am having trouble going from list to content. I've tried some of the code from [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-April/032077.html), but I get a bug with this part:

```
all.the.data <- lapply( all.the.files,  txt  , header=TRUE)
```

saying

```
 Error in match.fun(FUN) : object 'txt' not found
```

Any snippets of code that would clarify this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is `txt` is not a function. The link you pointed to is about the `read.csv` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers!

In the meanwhile, I also hacked a method on my own. Let me know if it is any useful:

```
library(foreign)

setwd("/path/to/directory")

files <-list.files()

data <- 0


for (f in files) {

tempData = scan( f, what="character")

data <- c(data,tempData)    

}
```

Answer (score 41):

You can try this:

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.txt")

#assuming tab separated values with a header    
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)read.table(x, header=T)) 

#assuming the same header/columns for all files
datafr = do.call("rbind", datalist)
```

Comment: slightly cleaner: `lapply(filelist, FUN=read.table, header=TRUE)`

Comment: Is there a way to add the filenames using this approach? So that the column headers of each dataframe start with (a part of) the filename?

Comment: Yes, this method has the problem that the filenames of datalist remains empty.

Answer (score 37):

There are three fast ways to read multiple files and put them into a single data frame or data table

**First get the list of all txt files (including those in sub-folders)**

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.txt$", 
                            full.names = TRUE)
```

**1) Use [`fread()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/fread) w/ [`rbindlist()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.0/topics/rbindlist) from the [`data.table`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) package**

```
#install.packages("data.table", repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
library(data.table)

# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
DT <- rbindlist(sapply(list_of_files, fread, simplify = FALSE),
                use.names = TRUE, idcol = "FileName")
```

**2) Use [`readr::read_table2()`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_table.html) w/ [`purrr::map_df()`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) from the [`tidyverse`](https://tidyverse.tidyverse.org/) framework:**

```
#install.packages("tidyverse", 
#                 dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
library(tidyverse)

# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
df <- list_of_files %>%
  set_names(.) %>%
  map_df(read_table2, .id = "FileName")
```

**3) (Probably the fastest out of the three) Use [`vroom::vroom()`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/vroom.html):**

```
#install.packages("vroom", 
#                 dependencies = TRUE, repos = "https://cran.rstudio.com")
library(vroom)

# Read all the files and create a FileName column to store filenames
df <- vroom(list_of_files, .id = "FileName")
```

**Note:** to clean up file names, use `basename` or `gsub` functions

[**Benchmark:**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vroom/vignettes/benchmarks.html) `readr` vs `data.table` vs `vroom` for big data

[image: vroom-benchmark]

---

**Edit 1**: to read multiple `csv` files and skip the `header` using [`readr::read_csv`](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html)

```
list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.csv$", 
                            full.names = TRUE)

df <- list_of_files %>%
  purrr::set_names(nm = (basename(.) %>% tools::file_path_sans_ext())) %>%
  purrr::map_df(read_csv, 
                col_names = FALSE,
                skip = 1,
                .id = "FileName")
```

**Edit 2**: to convert a pattern including a wildcard into the equivalent regular expression, use [`glob2rx()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5824164/786542)

Comment: How can I select only first three variables/columns of the list_of_files?

Comment: If you use `fread`: use `select = c(1:3)` or `select = c("colname 1",  "colname 2", "colname 3")`. If you use `read_table2`, check the argument `col_types = cols_only(colname1 = "i", colname2 = "d")` where `i` is integer and `d` is double. HTH

Comment: See my recent answer for more options for cleaning up filenames https://stackoverflow.com/a/49546846/786542

Comment: Relevant to `readr` usage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50651898/what-are-permissible-column-objects-of-the-form-col-used-in-readr/50652089#50652089

Comment: @Tung I am using your Edit 1 to merge several .csv files. The output is coming as row bind but I want the output as column bind. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: gotta upvote someone using `data.table`

Comment: @BappaDas: did you try `map_dfc()`?

Answer (score 11):

There is a really, really easy way to do this now: the **readtext** package.

```
readtext::readtext("path_to/your_files/*.txt")
```

It really is that easy.

Comment: This is a nice function, but `readtext` will just import all of the text into a single column. In most cases there will be additional manipulation required after this to make the data usable.

Comment: True, that's what the **quanteda** package is for.

Answer (score 5):

Look at the help for functions `dir()` aka `list.files()`.  This allows you get a list of files, possibly filtered by regular expressions, over which you could loop.

If you want to them all at once, you first have to have content in one file. One option would be to use `cat` to type all files to `stdout` and read that using `popen()`. See `help(Connections)` for more.

Comment: thanks, but still not clear. Check my edit :)