# Pattern matching using a wildcard

Tags: r, pattern-matching, wildcard

How do I identify a string using a wildcard?

I've found `glob2rx`, but I don't quite understand how to use it. I tried using the following code to pick the rows of the data frame that begin with the word `blue`:

```
# make data frame
a <- data.frame( x =  c('red','blue1','blue2', 'red2'))

# 1
result <- subset(a, x == glob2rx("blue*") )

# 2
test = ls(pattern = glob2rx("blue*"))
result2 <- subset(a, x == test )

# 3
result3 <- subset(a, x == pattern("blue*") )
```

However, neither of these worked. I'm not sure if I should be using a different function to try and do this.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you want to examine elements inside a dataframe you should not be using `ls()` which only looks at the names of objects in the current workspace (or if used inside a function in the current environment). Rownames or elements inside such objects are not visible to `ls()` (unless of course you add an environment argument to the `ls(.)`-call). Try using `grep()` which is the workhorse function for pattern matching of character vectors:

```
result <- a[ grep("blue", a$x) , ]  # Note need to use `a$` to get at the `x`
```

If you want to use subset then consider the closely related function `grepl()` which returns a vector of logicals can be used in the subset argument:

```
subset(a, grepl("blue", a$x))
      x
2 blue1
3 blue2
```

Edit: Adding one "proper" use of glob2rx within subset():

```
result <- subset(a,  grepl(glob2rx("blue*") , x) )
result
      x
2 blue1
3 blue2
```

I don't think I actually understood `glob2rx` until I came back to this question. (I did understand the scoping issues that were ar the root of the questioner's difficulties. Anybody reading this should now scroll down to Gavin's answer and upvote it.)

Comment: and if you want to exclude vectors than you can put the "-" operator before "grep"

Comment: @BondedDust    and what if I want only the elements which begin with "blue", and not the elements which have "blue" within?. E.g I would like select only "blue1" and "blue2" from this data.frame   `a <- data.frame( x =  c('red','blue1','blue2', 'red2','lightblue','darkblue'))`  I will be very grateful with your help.

Comment: The pattern for begins-with-"blue" would be `"^blue"`. See `?regex`

Answer (score 36):

`glob2rx()` converts a pattern including a wildcard into the equivalent regular expression. You then need to pass this regular expression onto one of R's pattern matching tools.

If you want to match `"blue*"` where `*` has the usual wildcard, *not* regular expression, meaning we use `glob2rx()` to convert the wildcard pattern into a useful regular expression:

```
> glob2rx("blue*")
[1] "^blue"
```

The returned object *is* a regular expression.

Given your data:

```
x <- c('red','blue1','blue2', 'red2')
```

we can pattern match using `grep()` or similar tools:

```
> grx <- glob2rx("blue*")
> grep(grx, x)
[1] 2 3
> grep(grx, x, value = TRUE)
[1] "blue1" "blue2"
> grepl(grx, x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

As for the selecting rows problem you posted

```
> a <- data.frame(x =  c('red','blue1','blue2', 'red2'))
> with(a, a[grepl(grx, x), ])
[1] blue1 blue2
Levels: blue1 blue2 red red2
> with(a, a[grep(grx, x), ])
[1] blue1 blue2
Levels: blue1 blue2 red red2
```

or via `subset()`:

```
> with(a, subset(a, subset = grepl(grx, x)))
      x
2 blue1
3 blue2
```

Hope that explains what `grob2rx()` does and how to use it?

Comment: It does. And I'm happy to learn something new even at this late date. I don't think I ever understood what a high-level function glob2rx was.

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track - the keyword you should be googling is Regular Expressions. R does support them in a more direct way than this using `grep()` and a few other alternatives.

Here's a detailed discussion: http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html

Answer (score 2):

If you really do want to use wildcards to identify specific variables, then you can use a combination of `ls()` and `grep()` as follows:

> `l = ls()`
>   `vars.with.result <- l[grep("result", l)]`

Answer (score 2):

You can also use package data.table and it's Like function, details given below
[How to select R data.table rows based on substring match (a la SQL like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630335/how-to-select-r-data-table-rows-based-on-substring-match-a-la-sql-like)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve your desired functionality would be through `dplyr()`

```
filter(str_detect(a, "blue"))
```

It would consider all instances of *blue* such as *blue1* and *blue2*

This command is basically the same as

```
filter(str_detect(a, "blue") == TRUE)
```

In case, the blues were in upper and lower case, you could do something like:

```
filter(str_detect(str_to_lower(a), "blue"))
```

I hope it helps someone who is looking for similar solutions.