# How to select R data.table rows based on substring match (a la SQL like)

Tags: r, data.table, string-matching

I have a data.table with a character column, and want to select only those rows that contain a substring in it.  Equivalent to SQL `WHERE x LIKE '%substring%'`

E.g.

```
> Months = data.table(Name = month.name, Number = 1:12)
> Months["mb" %in% Name]
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: Name,Number
```

How would I select only the rows where Name contains "mb"?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

`data.table` has a `like` function.

```
Months[like(Name,"mb")]
        Name Number
1: September      9
2:  November     11
3:  December     12
```

Or, `%like%` looks nicer :

```
> Months[Name %like% "mb"]
    Name Number
1: September      9
2:  November     11
3:  December     12
```

Note that `%like%` and `like()` use `grepl` (returns logical vector) rather than `grep` (returns integer locations). That's so it can be combined with other logical conditions :

```
> Months[Number<12 & Name %like% "mb"]
        Name Number
1: September      9
2:  November     11
```

and you get the power of regular expression search (not just % or * wildcard), too.

Comment: is there a way to use this command and update the table without `<-` , I was thinking in something like `Months[ Name== like(Name, "mb") ,] `

Comment: @RafaelPereira Have you looked at `?data.table` (examples), read the documentation and taken the DataCamp course?  `Months[like(Name,"mb"), someCol:=someValue]`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions @Matt-Dowle. Maybe I wasn't clear enough. [I meant to ask you this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32882768/subset-data-table-without-using).

Comment: @RafaelPereira I see, yes. As Frank has now pointed to there, I'd like this feature too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10791729/403310

Comment: Can you use this to search for multiple strings?

Comment: To negate it, use !like()

Answer (score 10):

The operator `%in%` does not do partial string matching
it is used for finding if values exist in another set of values i.e. `"a" %in% c("a","b","c")`

To do partial string matching you need to use the `grep()` function. 
You can use the `grep` to return an index of all columns with `"mb"` in it. Then subset the rows by that index

```
Months[grep("mb", Name)]    # data.table syntax slightly easier
```

Comment: Great thanks, infact `Months[grep("mb", Name)]` seems to work.

Comment: That should only work if you've defined Name as a separate vector somewhere else in your workspace. Be careful which variables you are using

Comment: Isn't this just working because this is a data.table vs data.frame?

Comment: Well then, how can we save the actual rows?