# Subset a data.table by a vector of substrings

Tags: r, substring, data.table, subset

Assuming we got this datatable `X` :

```
Random <- function(n=1, lenght=6){
  randomString <- c(1:n)
  for (i in 1:n){randomString[i] <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                   lenght, replace=TRUE),collapse="")}
  return(randomString)}

X <- data.table(A = rnorm(11000, sd = 0.8),
                B = rnorm(11000, mean = 10, sd = 3),
                C = sample( LETTERS[1:24], 11000, replace=TRUE),
                D = sample( letters[1:24], 11000, replace=TRUE),
                E = round(rnorm(11000,mean=25, sd=3)),
                F = round(runif(n = 11000,min = 1000,max = 25000)),
                G = round(runif(11000,0,200000)),
                H = Random(11000))
```

I want to subset it by some substring. Here, we will take `g`, `F` and `d` in column `H`

Here, we got a solution to do this for one substring : [How to select R data.table rows based on substring match (a la SQL like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630335/how-to-select-r-data-table-rows-based-on-substring-match-a-la-sql-like)

If we only want `g`, using `data.table` package :

```
X[like(H,pattern = "g")]
```

But my problem is to replicate this for `g`, `F` and `d` in a single operation.

```
Vec <- c("g","F","d")
Newtable <- X[like(H,pattern = Vec)]
Warning message:
In grep(pattern, levels(vector)) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Is there a way to do this whitout creating 3 tables, merging them and remove duplicates ?

Comment: I think `like` will take only a single element instead of a vector. Try using `Vectorize`

Comment: @Akrun You're right, and it is my problem. I don't know any function which is able to take a vector for this operation. Btw, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `grep` by `paste`ing the `vector` into a single string by `collapse`ing with `|`.

```
X[grep(paste(Vec, collapse="|"), H)]
```

Or we can use the same approach by `paste`ing the `pattern` vector `collapse`d by `|` (as suggested by @Tensibal)

```
X[like(H, pattern = paste(Vec, collapse="|"))]
```

Comment: `like` is using `grepl` under the hood, I assume the `paste ` method should work on `like`'s `pattern` argument also

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use this:

```
NewTable <- X[grepl("g",H) | grepl("F",H)  | grepl("d",H)]
```