# Identifying substring with non-letter characters in string in R data table

Tags: r

I am using data table and I want to mark out observations with a substring ".." in a longer string. After looking at [How to select R data.table rows based on substring match (a la SQL like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14630335/how-to-select-r-data-table-rows-based-on-substring-match-a-la-sql-like) I tried

```
like("Hi!..", "..")
```

which returns TRUE and

```
like("Hi!..", "Bye")
```

returns FALSE. However, surprisingly,

```
like("Hi!". "..")
```

returns TRUE! If this is a feature, why is that? And what can I use instead if I want to check a substring for non-letter characters?

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the special character "." with "\":

`like("Hi!", "\\.\\.")`

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `like()` is a regular expression and `.` has a special meaning in regex; it matches all characters. If you want to look for `.` literary, then add the argument `fixed = TRUE`.

```
like("Hi!", "..", fixed = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE
like("Hi!..", "..", fixed = TRUE)
# [1] TRUE
```