# Equivalent of SQL LIKE operator in R

Tags: regex, r

In an R script, I have a function that creates a data frame of files in a directory that have a specific extension.

The dataframe is always two columns with however many rows as there are files found with that specific extension.

The data frame ends up looking something like this:

```
|           Path           |   Filename  |
|:------------------------:|:-----------:|
| C:/Path/to/the/file1.ext |  file1.ext  |
| C:/Path/to/the/file2.ext |  file2.ext  |
| C:/Path/to/the/file3.ext |  file3.ext  |
| C:/Path/to/the/file4.ext |  file4.ext  |
```

Forgive the archaeic way that I express this question. I know that in SQL, you can apply `where` functions with `like` instead of `=`. So I could say `where Filename like '%1%' and it would pull out all files with a 1 in the name. Is there a way use something like this to set a variable in R?

I have a couple of different scripts that need to use the Filename pulled from this dataframe. The only reliable way I can think to tell the script which one to pull from is to set a variable like this.

Ultimately I would like these two (pseudo)expressions to yield the same thing.

```
x <- file1.ext
```

and

```
x like '%1%'
```

should both give x = `file1.ext`

Comment: what is the wildcard you would like to pull about?

Comment: @user1886721 I'm not sure I understand, but I'd like to be able to set a variable equal to `file1.ext` by saying something like `x like %1%` instead of `x <- file1.ext`

Comment: @user1886721 I guess its relevant to say that I'd like both of those expressions to yield the same value set to x

Comment: can you post the expected output from your data frame

Comment: so you would like everything that contains 1, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use grepl() as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823503/pattern-matching-using-a-wildcard)

```
subset(a, grepl("1", a$filename))
```

Or if you're coming from an SQL background, you might want to look into [sqldf](http://www.r-bloggers.com/manipulating-data-frames-using-sqldf-a-brief-overview/)

Comment: This doesn't work. When I use `paste0(subset(a, greql("1", a$filename)))` it returns `"character(0)" "character(0)"`

Comment: Okay, I had entered the column name incorrectly which is why it returned nothing.

However, it is returning a table. It was supposed to only return the Filename. or the second column entry for that. Now at this point, this is easy to work with for what I want to do, but I though I'd point out that it doesn't do exactly what I was asking for.

Comment: You can just add [,2] to the above formula.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `like` from `data.table` to get your sql like behaviour here.
From the documentation see this example

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(Name=c("Mary","George","Martha"), Salary=c(2,3,4))
DT[Name %like% "^Mar"]
```

for your problem suppose you have a `data.frame` `df` like this

```
                                  path  filename
1:            C:/Path/to/the/file1.ext file1.ext
2:            C:/Path/to/the/file2.ext file2.ext
3:            C:/Path/to/the/file3.ext file3.ext
4:            C:/Path/to/the/file4.ext file4.ext
```

do

```
library(data.table)
DT<-as.data.table(df)
DT[filename %like% "1"]
```

should give

```
                       path  filename
1: C:/Path/to/the/file1.ext file1.ext
```