# Could not find function "%like%"

Tags: r

Anytime I enter the following code in r:

`names(df$integers) %like% "%teen"`

I receive the following error

```
Error in names(df$integers) %like% "%teen" : 
could not find function "%like%"
```

What library am I missing?

Comment: It would be from `data.table`.  load the package `library(data.table); ?"%like%"`. if the package is not installed `install.packages('data.table'); library(data.table)`

Comment: Specifically, one of the not-accepted answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33018191

Comment: EnglishmanBob, if you have used it before on that computer and just don't know where it is, you can always type in `??\`%like%\`` (note the backticks) or `help.search("%like%")` and R will give you a bunch of fuzzy matches. On my computer, it identifies (as previously suggested) `data.table::like` (which includes both the `like(vec,ptn)` function and the `%like%` special).