# Merge mutiple .cbs files into one data frame that includes the file names in a new first column

Tags: r, dataframe, filenames

I am working with a large number of .cbs files in R. I have found a useful bit of code here ([How do you read in multiple .txt files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-in-multiple-txt-files-into-r) user Greg's response) which I changed from .txt to .cbs:

**Following three lines takes all the files and makes one `data.frame` "datafr" with all lines of code in:**

```
filelist = list.files(pattern = ".*.cbs")
```

**Assuming tab separated values with a header:**

```
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x)read.table(x, header=T))
```

**Assuming the same header/columns for all files:**

```
datafr = do.call("rbind", datalist)
```

This works really well for merging the files into one `data.frame`, however I would like to also include the name of the file that each line in the new merged data frame came from orignially. Ideally as a new first column of the `data.frame`. Can anyone please help me adapt this code?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following will do. Untested, since there is no data example.

```
datalist = lapply(seq_along(datalist), function(i){
        datalist[[i]]["filename"] <- filelist[[i]]
        datalist[[i]]
    })
```

I should also mention that I, and many others, prefer the assignment operator `<-` over `=`.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the upload example data (first post!), but your change to the datalist part worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Consider `transform`:

```
datalist = lapply(filelist, function(x) transform(read.table(x, header=T), filename=x))
```