# Removing the first observation string of dataset

Tags: r, nlp, dataset

I'm importing a bunch of files and trying to read all the characters into one variable. I need the order preserved. I found this code on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-in-multiple-txt-files-into-r/3397940) that does what I need but it adds the 0 in the front. so instead of the "0" i did

```
data <- ""
```

This still leaves my data variable with a blank at the beginning. I cannot subset it and remove all the "" blanks since my inputs have some that need to remain in there. How can I remove just the first blank "" or read all my files without having to add that blank there in the first place.

```
setwd("C:\\Users\\J\\Desktop\\nlp\\brown")
files <-list.files()
data <- 0
for (f in files) {
  tempData = scan( f, what="character")
  data <- c(data,tempData)    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to `NULL`

```
data <- NULL
```