# R - reading multiple data files at once

Tags: r, data.table, lapply

I am looking at parallel processing in R and was wondering if I could read in multiple txt files in parallel versus doing it sequentially. Reason for this is I have a shiny application and I want to cut down on the loading time and a large chunk is coming from loading the files.

Current situation:

```
Shipments_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_ship_month.txt', fill = TRUE)
ShipmentsYear_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_ship_year.txt', fill = TRUE)
Open_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_wip.txt', fill = TRUE)
WIP_Short_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmro_short.txt', fill = TRUE)
WIP_RTQT_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmro_sno_tasks_year.txt', fill = TRUE)
Invoiced_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_inv.txt', fill = TRUE)
```

I have seen examples of running in parallel but they all end with combining all of the files. Each file I import, I want as a separate dataframe.

Here are some examples:

[How do you read in multiple .txt files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-in-multiple-txt-files-into-r)

https://www.r-bloggers.com/import-all-text-files-in-a-folder-with-parallel-execution/

Ideal situation (although I know this isn't the code):

```
RunParallel {
    Shipments_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_ship_month.txt', fill = TRUE)
    ShipmentsYear_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_ship_year.txt', fill = TRUE)
    Open_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_wip.txt', fill = TRUE)
    WIP_Short_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmro_short.txt', fill = TRUE)
    WIP_RTQT_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmro_sno_tasks_year.txt', fill = TRUE)
    Invoiced_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_inv.txt', fill = TRUE)
}
```

**After comment from below**

```
    tic <- Sys.time()
Shipments_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_ship_month.txt', fill = TRUE)
ShipmentsYear_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_ship_year.txt', fill = TRUE)
Open_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_wip.txt', fill = TRUE)
WIP_Short_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmro_short.txt', fill = TRUE)
WIP_RTQT_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmro_sno_tasks_year.txt', fill = TRUE)
Invoiced_Raw <- read.delim('/srv/samba/share/SAP data/_zmrosales_inv.txt', fill = TRUE)
toc <- Sys.time()
Sequential <- toc - tic


tic <- Sys.time()
file <- c("/srv/samba/share/SAP data//_zmrosales_ship_month.txt", 
          "/srv/samba/share/SAP data//_zmrosales_ship_year.txt", 
          "/srv/samba/share/SAP data//_zmrosales_inv.txt",
          "/srv/samba/share/SAP data//_zmrosales_wip.txt",
          "/srv/samba/share/SAP data//_zmro_short.txt",
          "/srv/samba/share/SAP data//_zmro_sno_tasks_year.txt")
x2 <- lapply(file, data.table::fread)

Shipments_Raw <- as.data.frame(x2[1])
ShipmentsYear_Raw <- as.data.frame(x2[2])
Invoiced_Raw <- as.data.frame(x2[3])
Open_Raw <- as.data.frame(x2[4])
WIP_Short_Raw <- as.data.frame(x2[5])
WIP_RTQT_Raw <- as.data.frame(x2[6])

toc <- Sys.time()
Lapply <- toc - tic

Sequential
Lapply
```

Difference in time:

```
> Sequential
Time difference of 6.011156 secs
> Lapply
Time difference of 0.8015034 secs
```

Comment: `lapply(files, data.table::fread)`

Comment: Awesome! I didn't realize that gave me the data sets in elements and not merge them. If you put your answer below, I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `lapply` in combination with `data.table`s super fast `fread`:

```
lapply(files, data.table::fread)
```