# Combining many csv files keeping the file name in R

Tags: r

I have a folder with many csv files. Each csv file has the same number of columns. I would like to combine them creating a column with the file name. I've seen similar post about it but I cannnot get it to work. I'm trying the following script. Any help will be much appreciated

```
library(plyr)
csvfilenames <- list.files("/Users/PAM/Desktop/CSVFilesToMerge/",
                           pattern="*.csv", all.files=FALSE, full.names=FALSE)
csvfilenames

library(plyr)
CombinedData = ldply(csvfilenames, function(filename) {
dum = read.table(filename, header=TRUE, fill = TRUE, sep=";")
dum$Filename = csvfilenames
return(dum)
})
CombinedData`
```

---

This is my next attempt with purrr but it doesnt work

```
library(readr) # for read_csv()
library(purrr) #for map(), reduce()

data_path<-"/Users/PAM/Desktop/TestCSVFilesToMerge/"

files <- dir(data_path, pattern = "*.csv") # get file names
files


data <- files %>% # read in all the files, appending the path before the filename
map(~ read_csv(file.path(data_path, .))) %>% 
reduce(rbind)
data
```

Comment: what about base R with lapply and read.table() ? Then you can use the names of the list to `dplyr::bind_rows()` into a unified `data.frame`

Comment: `library(purrr); combined_data <- csvfilenames %>% map_dfr(read.csv2, .id = 'filename')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105838/786542

Comment: This is my next attempt with purrr but I get an error

`library(readr)` # for read_csv()
`library(dbplyr)` # for mutate()
`library(tidyr)` # for unnest()
`library(purrr)` #for map(), reduce()

`data_path<-"/Users/PAM/Desktop/TestCSVFilesToMerge/"`

`files <- dir(data_path, pattern = "*.csv")` # get file names

`data <- files %>%` # read in all the files, appending the path before the filename
`map(~ read_csv(file.path(data_path, .))) %>% 
  reduce(rbind)`
`data`

Answer (score 0):

This should give you exactly what you want,

```
csvfilenames <- list.files("/Users/PAM/Desktop/CSVFilesToMerge/",
                       pattern="*.csv", all.files=FALSE, full.names=FALSE)

for(i in 1:length(csvfilenames))
{
temp<-read.csv(paste(csvfilenames[i])) #give path if its not your wd
temp$filename_tag<-paste(csvfilenames[i])

list[[i]]<-temp
}

outfile<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,list))
```

Comment: Thank you Alok. However, I include the path in the read.csv as you mentioned `temp<-read.csv(file="/Users/PAM/Desktop/CSVFilesToMerge/firstCSVfile.csv", sep=";", header=T, paste(csvfilenames[i]))` and I get the following error "EOF within quoted stringError in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "filename_tag", value = "firstCSVfile.csv") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0"

Comment: Just change the line to, temp<-read.csv(file=paste("/Users/PAM/Desktop/CSVFilesToMerge/",csvfilenames[i],sep=""), sep=";", header=T)

Comment: Hi Alok, Thanks for your suggestion but I get a Error in list[[i]] <- temp : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable. Do you have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: Hi Alok, see the code in my next post. The one where I said that "I managed to get it to work. However..." (the one below this one). The problem is that when I put all the "list" together it creates a lot of new rows. I think the problem in in the `outfile<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,list))` because the "temp2" files that the loop creates seem to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work. However, I was wondering if someone could help me cleaning up the script a bit. This script also transposes the data and therefore I have to manually delete all the extra rows that creates (one per column). I think the problem is in the last line of the script when I transform the list in a data frame.

```
csvfilenames <- list.files("/Users/carlos/Desktop/TestCSVFilesToMerge/",
                   pattern="*.csv", all.files=FALSE, full.names=FALSE) #creates a list with the file names
csvfilenames

for(i in 1:length(csvfilenames))  

{
a=csvfilenames[i]
temp1<-read.csv(file=paste("/Users/carlos/Desktop/TestCSVFilesToMerge/",a,sep=""),sep=";", header=T)
temp2<-cbind("FileName"=a,temp1[,1:ncol(temp1)]) #add a column called FileName in position 1

list[[i]]<-temp2
}

outfile<-as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,list))
outfile
```

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49807986/edit) button below your question to add this information in your question itself instead of posting it here. Or perhaps edit this so it is actually an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above scenario i have 2 csv files which i have read
CSV1:

2016    2016    2017    2017    2018    2018
    Value   % vs. PY    Value   % vs. PY    Value   % vs. PY
Data1 2018-09   23663       2,757   5.7 %
Data2 2018-08                   7687686 15.1 %
Data2 2018-09                   987987  15.2 %

CSV2:
2016    2016    2017    2017    2018    2018
    Value   % vs. PY    Value   % vs. PY    Value   % vs. PY
Data1 2018-09   456     3000  4%

i would like to add filename as column name too.
i used following:

```
x1= read.csv(choose.files(),F,"\t", skipNul = FALSE)
x2= read.csv(choose.files(),F,"\t", skipNul = FALSE)
merged_files= do.call(rbind, list(x1= x1, x2= x2))
```

but its adding x1in each row. Cna anybody help?
I tried to use the code above but its giing me error In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file.