# R - variable name in loop

Tags: r, loops, variables

I've got let's say 10 csv files with names like as

```
file_1_tail.csv 
file_2_tail.csv 
file_3_tail.csv  
...  
file_10_tail.csv
```

The only difference in name is in the number (1 to 10). Each has the same structure -  1000 rows and 100 columns.

I need to read them to the R, select specific columns and write as new file. My code for one file is below:

```
file_2_tail = read_csv("file_2_tail.csv")
file_2_tail_selected = file_2_tail[,c(1:7,30)])
write.csv2(file_2_tail_selected, file = "file_2_selected.csv")
```

And now I want to use loop to automate this for all ten files.

```
for (i in 1:10){    
file_"i"_tail = read_csv("file_"i"_tail.csv")
file_"i"_tail_selected = file_"i"_tail[,c(1:7,30)]
write.csv2(file_"i"_tail_selected, file = "file_"i"_selected.csv")
}
```

And of course it doesn't work - i is not readable in this notation. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign `read_csv` results to a string like that. Instead you can just store it in a temporary variable `tmp`

```
for (i in 1:10){    
  tmp <- read_csv(paste0("file_", i, "_tail.csv"))
  tmp <- tmp[, c(1:7,30)]
  write.csv2(tmp, file = paste0("file_", i, "_selected.csv"))
}
```

Btw this is probably a more efficient way to read multiple files

```
library(tidyverse)

filePattern <- "\\.csv$"
fileList <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = FALSE,
                       pattern = filePattern, full.names = TRUE)

result <- fileList %>%
  purrr::set_names(nm = (basename(.) %>% tools::file_path_sans_ext())) %>%
  purrr::map_df(read_csv, .id = "FileName") %>% 
  select(1:7, 30)
result
```

Comment: @anba: not a problem. Btw I updated my answer to include a more efficient way to read multiple files

Comment: @anba: btw, you can select the columns you want directly within `readr::read_csv` to make it more efficient. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50652089/