# Read CSV files from different folders into data frames, append data from existing CSVs/dataframes

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

i'm trying to read csv files into data frames in R. I've already managed to cycle through defined folders, read the csv files and assign them in order to create a dataframe with the name. However, i cant seem to append data if a dataframe already exists. If a dataframe already exists i want to append the new data on the bottom and not just replace the whole thing.

This is what i have working so far:

```
fileName <- list.files("\\path\\subfolder", "*csv", full.names = FALSE)
fileName <- gsub(".csv", "", fileName)

for (i in 1:length(testPath)) {
tempVar <-  read.csv(testPath[i])
assign(fileName[i], tempVar)
}
```

This only cycles through one folder, I know how to make it cycle through multiple folders. However when I run this code twice it will not append data to the dataframes, instead just create them again from a csv

Thanks for the help!

UPDATE: I FIGURED IT OUT SEE BELOW

Comment: Lots of options at this very well travelled duplicate (though you should avoid any solution using `assign`): https://stackoverflow.com/q/11433432/324364

Comment: Hi, this post is the one i used as base for my code above. However, it doesnt append any data to existing data frames when looping through differnet folders. Also tried the update approach using list2env(lapply())), if i run the code multiple times i cant get the data to append

Comment: The solutions there aren't organized in the clearest fashion, but many of them use `do.call(rbind,...)` or `dplyr::bind_rows` or the equivalent from data.table to do what you want. It's all there, you just have to read carefully and slowly, since, as I said, it's not organized as cleanly as it could.

Comment: There, I edited the first answer there, which is probably the only one you really ventured into. Hopefully it points you in a more helpful direction now.

Comment: @robs: this might help too https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105838/786542

Comment: Just figured it out posting the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I'm pretty new to R so I did a workaround creating a temporary dataframe if one exists and then merging it with the old one. In case any one is looking for the code in the future, heres what i did.

Its not pretty but it works:

```
mainFilesOutputFolder <- paste("\\\\network\\folder\\", sep="")
scanSubFolders <- c("subfolder1", "subfolder2", "subfolder3")

for (k in 1:length(scanSubFolders)) {
  csvOutputs <- list.files(paste(mainFilesOutputFolder, scanSubFolders[k], "\\", sep=""), "*csv", full.names = TRUE)

  fileName <- list.files(paste(mainFilesOutputFolder, scanSubFolders[k], "\\", sep=""), "*csv", full.names = FALSE)
  fileName <- gsub(".csv", "", fileName)

  for (i in 1:length(csvOutputs)) {
    df_name <- fileName[i]
    if (exists(df_name)) {
      mergedDF <- rbind(get(fileName[i]),read.csv(csvOutputs[i]))
      assign(fileName[i], mergedDF)
      }else{
        #false
        assign(fileName[i], read.csv(csvOutputs[i]))
      } 
  }
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Note that you're growing object `mergedDF` inside a loop. This is very memory inefficient and not recommended in R. See these great posts: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://winvector.github.io/Accumulation/) & 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398)