# Merging multiple .xls files in R

Tags: r, merge, lapply, xls, rbind

I am trying to merge a list of `.xls` files in google drive. I have now managed to create a list of all the files I need, but for some reason I still can't manage to merge them, this is the code I have so far:

```
library(googledrive)
inputfiles <- drive_ls(path = "Email It In", pattern = "*PDOL_dataexport", n_max = 50)

library(readxl)
df.list<- lapply(inputfiles,function(x) read_xls(x))
library(dplyr)
consolidated_data<-bind_rows(df.list)
```

The second part of the code throws up the following error:

```
Error: `path` must be a string
```

I must be entering the path (inputfiles) incorrectly for lapply, can someone please help?

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) help?

Comment: This might help too https://stackoverflow.com/a/48105838/786542

Answer (score 1):

I have found readxl package to be more friendly when importing .xlsx files or .xls files.
Assuming each of the .xls file contains just one sheet to be imported the below code should work for you.

```
library(googledrive)

drive_find(n_max = 50)

library(readxl)

inputfiles <- list.files(pattern = "*PDOL_dataexport")

df.list<-lapply(inputfiles ,function(x) read_xls(x))

library(dplyr)

consolidated_data<-bind_rows(df.list)
```

Comment: But how do I merge them? Please see my last question.

Comment: I have edited the answer. The last two lines of code will solve the problem

Comment: Hi, that helped thank you. However I am still having difficulties, I have edited the question - could you please help?