# How can I sum a column of multiple datasets that do not have the same structure?

Tags: r

I have several files (20) with the same column structure but with different rows structure. All are composed of two columns, the first are factors and the second are integers. I want to sum the column of integers for the factors that are repeated and the new ones that are simply added. How could I combine and sum the ones already repeated?

I've thought about combining cbind and tapply but I really do not know how to carry this out.

A simple example of the structure of the files:

```
Shop   Clients     Shop  Clients     Shop Clients
 A        9          D      8          A     5
 B        7          A      4          R     4
 C        4          F      3          C     3
 D        2          B      1          B     2
```

I expect the output:

```
Shop Clients
A      18 
B      10
C       7
D      10
F       3
R       4
```

I read the different files in a loop, creating a dataset for each of them, so that the dataset shows City1$Shop and City1$Clients for example. This case is only for 20 files but I would like to know how to work with more (for example 100).
How could I solve this problem by reading the datasets in this way?

```
f<-function(x){
  read.delim2("p01.txt",header=T,sep="\t",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
for(i in x){
total<-f(i)
#Here I suppose I would combine and sum the datasets
}
```

Comment: So with the edit it now seems that you do not have **one** file with multiple columns named `"Shop"` and `"Clients"`. The example above are in fact several files? If so the posted solutions probably do not work.

Comment: Also, is there a pattern in the filenames? If this is the case then they can be read in with `fnames <- list.files(pattern = <something>)` followed by a `lapply` loop. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-in-multiple-txt-files-into-r) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-at-once).

Comment: I thought at first that I had explained it in a clear way, but when I saw the answers I realized that I had to edit it and show in detail how I read the data. It's my first question and I'm learning to ask questions in a clear way. Sorry!
I had thought about creating a "total" dataframe in which to add and sum each dataframe that I am reading, or is it better all at once? I'm stuck with this problem.

Comment: Do **all filenames** start with a `"p"` followed by one or more digits and have a `.txt` extension?

Comment: Yeah, I read them in this way ` x<-list.files(pattern=".txt") ` I have the problem to put them together and sum the columns

Comment: I mean, I've managed to read them in a loop, the problem is what to do next with them.

Comment: See the edit, I believe this is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to use `aggregate` after reshaping the data to a long format.

```
inx <- grep("Shop", names(df1))
long <- do.call(rbind, lapply(inx, function(i) df1[i:(i + 1)]))
aggregate(Clients ~ Shop, long, sum)
#  Shop Clients
#1    A      18
#2    B      10
#3    C       7
#4    D      10
#5    F       3
#6    R       4
```

**Edit.**
After the edit to the question, I believe the following does what is asked. I will once again use `aggregate`.

```
fnames <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt")
df_list <- lapply(fnames, read.table, header = TRUE)
df_all <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
aggregate(Clients ~ Shop, data = df_all, sum)
```

Comment: It works! I was complicating the problem with a loop, it is much simpler than I thought. Thank you very much for the help and patience!

Comment: What if I have multiple headers not just two as in( Clients ~ Shop)??

Comment: @AmalNasir Can you give an example? It is possible to aggregate by several columns, say, `Clients ~ Shop + Month`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes, I posted my question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67692461/sum-up-tables-results-from-multiple-sheets-into-one-table-in-r

Answer (score 1):

We can `melt` the data into 'long' format by specifying the `measure` columns with `patterns` of column names as 'Shop' 'Clients', then grouped by 'Shop' get the `sum` of 'Clients'

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^Shop", "^Clients"), 
  value.name = c("Shop", "Clients"))[, .(Clients = sum(Clients)), by = Shop]
#    Shop Clients
#1:    A      18
#2:    B      10
#3:    C       7
#4:    D      10
#5:    F       3
#6:    R       4
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfc(list(Shop = "Shop", Clients = "Clients"), ~
    df1 %>%
       select(matches(.x)) %>% 
       unlist) %>% 
  group_by(Shop) %>% 
  summarise(Clients = sum(Clients))
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  Shop  Clients
#  <chr>   <int>
#1 A          18
#2 B          10
#3 C           7
#4 D          10
#5 F           3
#6 R           4
```

---

Or with `rowsum` from `base R`

```
i1 <- grepl("^Shop", names(df1))
rowsum(unlist(df1[!i1]), group =  unlist(df1[i1]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Shop = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), Clients = c(9L, 
 7L, 4L, 2L), Shop.1 = c("D", "A", "F", "B"), Clients.1 = c(8L, 
 4L, 3L, 1L), Shop.2 = c("A", "R", "C", "B"), Clients.2 = 5:2), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 select_at(vars(contains("Shop"))) %>%
 gather(var1, val1) %>%
 bind_cols(df %>%
 select_at(vars(contains("Client"))) %>%
 gather(var2, val2)) %>%
 group_by(Shop = val1) %>%
 summarise(Clients = sum(val2))

  Shop  Clients
  <chr>   <int>
1 A          18
2 B          10
3 C           7
4 D          10
5 F           3
6 R           4
```

The same with `base R`:

```
long_df <- data.frame(Shop = stack(df[, grepl("Shop", names(df))])[, 1], 
Clients = stack(df[, grepl("Client", names(df))])[, 1])
aggregate(Clients ~ Shop, long_df, sum)

  Shop Clients
1    A      18
2    B      10
3    C       7
4    D      10
5    F       3
6    R       4
```