# readr::read_csv() adds first column X1 with row numbers

Tags: r, large-files, readr

I am importing a csv file with `read_csv()` using the following command:

```
motus <- read_csv("motus_tables/TEST_metabar_motus_miseq_nov_12S.csv", 
                  col_names = TRUE,
                  progress = show_progress())
```

The issue is that this adds a first column X1 with numbers for the rows. I don't know why and I don't know how to fix it! I am trying to use this option instead of the `read.table` because the file I will have to read is huge and the `read.table` takes forever. I take any other suggestions as well to handle large csv files fast, with a progress bar being a plus!

I am running R v.3.6.2 in RStudio v.1.3

Comment: Without seeing the data it's difficult to know why. Have you tried `vroom()` or `fread()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-in-multiple-txt-files-into-r/48105838#48105838?

Comment: ugh, so i think i'm having trouble figuring out the rownames situation and how to save the files. for the file above, my rownames were numbers, so when writing it to csv (write.csv) it would create a first column with numbers indeed. if i assign a column as rownames, when i read the file (read_csv) it creates the first column with that column that i assigned as rowname. however, for some reason, i have another data.frame that was written and read the same way, but when reading (read_csv) it replaces my rownames to numbers! it does not add it as an extra column.

Comment: See the `column_to_rownames()` function in the "tibble" package, this might help.  My advice is leave the row names as numbers, use the first column for labels (if necessary) and use "row.names =FALSE" when using `write.csv()`

Comment: thanks... yeah, i agree. i'm just gonna do the column_to_rownames afterwards. i was trying to avoid multiple steps because the data is so big, but i think this is the easiest. and thanks for the tip on writing the csv. that's helpful! :)