# Read and concatinates files from the list

Tags: r

I have a file (list) which contains the file name as like this

```
data/InTel.txt
data/Dell.txt
data/Asus.txt
```

I need to load all above files from the folder called data and concatenate as All

```
All <- lapply(list,function(i){read.delim(i)})
```

But I got error like this " Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument "

Is there any better way to solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-multiple-txt-files-into-r

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read multiple .txt files into R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397885/how-do-you-read-multiple-txt-files-into-r)

Comment: Not really.....